# Why are those Null rows disappearing when I specify more than one value in an WHERE statement in PostreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

For privacy reasons I'm not allowed to post the exact code here but I'll give something similar...

I have two subqueries that are left joined together. The first query just gets a list of dates

```
SELECT DATE
FROM (
    SELECT (NOW()::DATE - EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INT - 7)::DATE + d.DATE AS DATE
    FROM generate_series(0, 99) AS d(DATE)
    WHERE (NOW()::DATE - EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INT - 7) + d.DATE BETWEEN (NOW()::DATE - EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INT - 7)
            AND (NOW()::DATE - EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INT - 3)::DATE
    ) AS tr
```

Which returns

```
   date    
------------
 2018-01-14
 2018-01-15
 2018-01-16
 2018-01-17
 2018-01-18
```

Then I need to left join to another subquery to return value from those dates.

Let's say this next table looks like

```
 date           name    info
 2018-01-01     Alice     21
 2018-01-01     Brent     4
 2018-01-02     Alice     6
 2018-01-02     Brent     1
 2018-01-03     Brent     8
 2018-01-04     Brent     56
 2018-01-05    Brent      4
 2018-01-14    Alice     4
 2018-01-14    Brent     2
 2018-01-15    Alice     10
 2018-01-16    Alice     5
 2018-01-17    Brent     7
```

So I left joined both queries and specify which name I want

```
SELECT table1.DATE,
    table2.NAME,
    table2.info
FROM (
    SELECT DATE
    FROM (
        SELECT (NOW()::DATE - EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INT - 7)::DATE + d.DATE AS DATE
        FROM generate_series(0, 99) AS d(DATE)
        WHERE (NOW()::DATE - EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INT - 7) + d.DATE BETWEEN (NOW()::DATE - EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INT - 7
                        )
                AND (NOW()::DATE - EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INT - 3)::DATE
        ) AS tr
    ) AS table1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT NAME,
        DATE,
        info
    FROM lookup
    WHERE = 'Alice'
    ) AS TABLE 2
    ON table1.DATE = table2.DATE
```

Then I get something like

```
     2018-01-14    Alice     4
     2018-01-15    Alice     10
     2018-01-16    Alice     5
     2018-01-17    NULL      NULL
```

Similarly, specifying Brent returns

```
2018-01-14    Brent     2
 2018-01-15    NULL      NULL
 2018-01-16    NULL      NULL
 2018-01-17    Brent     7
```

But if I don't specify any name or have a WHERE in ('Alice', 'Brent'), I get

```
 2018-01-14    Alice     4
 2018-01-14    Brent     2
 2018-01-15    Alice     10
 2018-01-16    Alice     5
 2018-01-17    Brent     7
```

And all the Null rows dissapear. I need those NULL rows to be included in the analysis. I tried including NULLs with a where statement but that doesn't work. I'm aware that I can do a UNION ALL, but in the real case, there are just way too many names to go through. Is there another way to include all rows so it returns the following instead?

```
 2018-01-14    Alice     4
 2018-01-15    Alice     10
 2018-01-16    Alice     5
 2018-01-17    NULL      NULL 
 2018-01-14    Brent     2
 2018-01-15    NULL      NULL
 2018-01-16    NULL      NULL
 2018-01-17    Brent     7
```

Comment: So... if you have 50 names to go through and 40 of those don't have data for '2018-01-17' you will have 40 records like `2018-01-17 NULL NULL`?

Comment: That's what I need yes. But it only returns the 10 that are not NULL

Comment: The reason is because I need to assign a value to each of those NULL values based on the date it is associated with.

Comment: How do you get your list of many names? Is that in a separate table, or is it like `SELECT distinct name FROM lookup;`, or is it just a list?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the names are part of that second table I'm looking at. It contains name, date and info. But there is also a separate table that has all the names as well, though it may be irrelevant here..

Comment: I believe it is relevant because a cross join between your distinct dates and your distinct names will give you a derived table upon which you can left join over to your lookup table. Check out my updated answer for how that would work.

Comment: Currently your `WHERE = 'Alice'` and `WHERE in ('Alice', 'Brent')` are syntactically invalid so it's hard to say what your real, non-obsfucated query actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is a table with the list of names you are after (perhaps even a temp table?) you can cross join this list of names with your generated dates, then join to your lookup table.

Something like:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE names ( name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO names VALUES ('alice'),('brent');

SELECT crossjoin.DATE,
    lookup.NAME,
    lookup.info
FROM (
    SELECT tr.DATE,
        names.NAME
    FROM (
        SELECT (NOW()::DATE - EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INT - 7)::DATE + d.DATE AS DATE
        FROM generate_series(0, 99) AS d(DATE)
        WHERE (NOW()::DATE - EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INT - 7) + d.DATE BETWEEN (NOW()::DATE - EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INT - 7
                        )
                AND (NOW()::DATE - EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INT - 3)::DATE
        ) AS tr
        , names
    ) AS crossjoin
LEFT JOIN lookup
    ON crossjoin.DATE = lookup.DATE
        AND crossjoin.NAME = lookup.NAME
```

Comment: I noted in my original post that I'm aware that I can do a UNION ALL, but that I have way too many names in the actual table to do that. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: I have updated the code to do this logic without a UNION.

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you!!

Comment: I'm so glad it helped out! That was a fun exercise :)